# KeyCloak : Disable account after 5 incorrect login attempts, and send an email to the user to reactivate the account

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I'm working on a project with KeyCloak where the requirement is after 5 incorrect login attempts from the user, the account needs to be suspended, and an email should be sent to the user to reactivate the account

So far I couldn't find this configuration, can you please tell me if it's possible? And if yes, where the option is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the account lock in the:

Realm Settings -> Security Defenses -> Brute Force Detection.

You can specify there if the lock should be permanent, login failures count and couple more settings to consider.

As for sending email, I believe to achieve that you would have to create your own extension using SPI, most probably by extending UserNamePasswordForm.
Can't share the entire code, but here is an example of how to send email using predefined template - all info can be found in the KC documentation.

```
private void authCodeEmailSend(AuthenticationFlowContext context, UserModel user) throws EmailException {
    Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap();
    FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider emailTemplateProvider = new FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider(context.getSession(), new FreeMarkerUtil());
    emailTemplateProvider.setRealm(context.getRealm());
    emailTemplateProvider.setUser(user);
    emailTemplateProvider.setAuthenticationSession(context.getAuthenticationSession());
    // code cut for attributes map fill
    emailTemplateProvider.send(
            "emailAccountBlockedSubject",
            "email-brute-force-error.ftl", attributes);
}
```

You can use code similar to below to check the current failure count:

```
public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
// (...)
    UserModel user = KeycloakModelUtils.findUserByNameOrEmail(context.getSession(), context.getRealm(), retrieveUsername(context));
    UserLoginFailureModel failure = context.getSession().loginFailures().getUserLoginFailure(context.getRealm(), user.getId());
    int countFailure = failure.getNumFailures();
}
```